# Iterating through Django Rest API and obtaining an error

Tags: python, json, django, loops, django-rest-framework

I have the following Django Rest API structure:

```
[
   {
        "title": "Project 1",
        "description": "API projects",
        "members": [
            {
                "latest_activity": "15151020",
                "first_name": "AleX",
                "minutes_last_week": 0,
                "last_name": "Mol",
                "id": 23,
                "minutes_total": 30,
                "minutes_today": 0
            },
            {
                "latest_activity": "1515181664",
                "first_name": "Annie",
                "minutes_last_week": 0,
                "last_name": "Az",
                "id": 47,
                "minutes_total": 20,
                "minutes_today": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Project 2",
        "description": "Developer test (internal   project",
        "members": [
            {
                "latest_activity": "1511600",
                "first_name": "Ivan",
                "minutes_last_week": 0,
                "last_name": "XJJNX",
                "id": 18,
                "minutes_total": 10,
                "minutes_today": 0
            },
            {
                "latest_activity": "1516985",
                "first_name": "Lauren",
                "minutes_last_week": 0,
                "last_name": "Gom",
                "id": 39,
                "minutes_total": 560,
                "minutes_today": 0
            }
        ]
    }    
]
```

What I want to do is iterate over this API, and obtain all the project names and developers that have been working in each project, so I developed the following function:

```
    def execute():
        respuesta = requests.get('http://projd.herokuapp.com/api/v1/activities/?format=json', auth=('xxx','xxx'))
        upresponse = respuesta.json()

        for team in range(0, len(upresponse)-1):upresponse[team]["members"]
            print(team["first_name"]+" "+ team["last_name"] + " has been working in " + team["latest_activity"])
```

And I'm doing something wrong and I'm obtaining the following error: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

I can't understand why.

Comment: Why do you dumps then immediately loads? That makes no sense, you just get back what you started with. You don't need to do *either* of those.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're right, I already noticed and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
for project in upresponse:    #Iterate over projects
    for team in project["members"]:   #Iterate over members
        print(team["first_name"] + " " + team["last_name"] + " has been working in " + team["latest_activity"])
```

**Output:**

```
AleX Mol has been working in 15151020
Annie Az has been working in 1515181664
Ivan XJJNX has been working in 1511600
Lauren Gom has been working in 1516985
```

Comment: It actually helps! And for example if in my sentence I want to add the project name how can I do that? Because 'title' is outside of members.

Comment: You can add `project["title"]` to your print statement.